# При обновлении аудио файла, <audio> воспроизводит всегда первую запись

Tags: html, аудио

Создал страничку, которая берет озвучку гугла и записывает в файл.
Этот файл я воспроизвожу через тег `<audio>`. Каждое обновление страницы, это новый mp3 файл с тем же именем. Смотрю через консоль, файл не хэширован, можно воспроизвести отдельно через вкладку сеть. Но когда тыкаю воспроизведение на страничке, воспроизводится первый файл, который я прослушивал.
Использовал `<embed>`, работает, только если тыкать F5, такой подход не очень и нужно использовать `<audio>` вместо `<embed>`. Код html:

```
<div class="col-4">
                    {*<embed controls id="tts-audio" class="form-control" src="audio/{$session_id}.mp3"/>*}
                    <audio controls="controls">
                        <source src="audio/{$session_id}.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis" />
                     <source src="audio/{$session_id}.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
                </div>
```

[Ссылка на страницу, где используется embed](https://ragnoboy.ru/autocorrect.php)

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в $smarty, который я использовал. Для него никакого обновления не происходило, так как название файла оставалось неизменным, как и сама страница.

```
$smarty->force_compile;
```

Частично помогает, но использовать на реальных системах его не рекомендуется.
Для своей проблемы, я переопределил имена, которыми называются mp3 файлы, помогло.